# C Problems with menu

Tags: c, menu

I am having problems with the menu function of my program. The last 2 parts of  the  printf for the menu are continuing onto the next function.

Code for menu function -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void enter(char names[16][20]);
void menu();

int main()
{
    char names[16][20];
    int i;

    printf("Please enter the names of the players:\n");

        /*Making the user enter 16 times*/
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) 
    {   
        scanf("%9s", &names[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    /*Clearing Screen*/
    system("cls");

    menu();
    return names[16][20];
}


void menu(char names[][20])
{
    int choice;

    printf("Please select one of the following options:\n\n"
            "Press 1 to enter game  results\n"
            "Press 2 to display the current round\n"
            "Press 3 to display the players advancing to the next round\n"
            "Press 4 to display the previous round\n"
            "Press 5 to exit the program\n");
    system("cls");


    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if(choice == 1)
    {
        enter(names);
        system("cls");
    }

}


void enter(char names[][20])
{

    int result;
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int p, c, j, l, i;
    char winner[8][8];


        system("cls");

        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            printf("\n\n%s vs %s",names[i],names[i+8]);

            score1 = 0;
            score2 = 0;

            for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                printf("\n\nEnter game %d results, press 1 if %s won or"
                       " 2 if %s won :\n",(j+1), names[i], names[i+8]);
                scanf("%d", &result);

                if(result == 1)
                {
                    score1++;
                }
                if(result == 2)
                {
                    score2++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Somehow the press 4 and 5 options are getting into the next next function

Image - 
https://gyazo.com/7e99cfb42a18d04a144d3d139409d6ec

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I honestly have no idea why it is happening, but before it started happening I moved my menu out of main into its own function. I will try and narrow it down

Comment: You haven't shown enough info. Please read the MCVE link provided above. It looks like you have memory corruption in code that you have not shown. As a minimum you need to show how `menu` is being called and also what `enter` does.

Comment: I have changed the code, I have stripped down all the code that I could and  it is reproducing the issue I am having

Comment: `menu();`. Hmm..calling the function with no parameters even though it is defined to take a parameter. I'm going to stick my neck out and say that that is never going to work and that it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks! changing that to 'menu(names);' has fixed the issue i was having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I ran your code with some changes and it ran fine, without the two `printf` lines that you have shown in your image file.

1. First thing is, the `menu()` function you have written wrong. It's prototype showing that it takes no arguments while in it's declaration it take an array. You need to pass the `names` array to menu function as you are going to pass it to the `enter` function. So, both the functions `menu()` and `enter()` will be taking `names` array as an argument.
2. I used the code without `system("cls")` function as my compiler didn't find it.

So, it has worked at my side, I am getting feeling like, `system("cls")` is causing you the problem that you shown in the image.